# Should I implement my own mean, std. deviation and median in C++?

Tags: c++

Should I implement my own mean, std. deviation and median in C++, or there is already existing code I should use? I need to calculate these for a std::vector.

Thanks

Comment: For the mean, use `std::accumulate / vec.size()`.

Comment: For median, you can use [std::nth_element](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/nth_element/) (may have to run twice), or just [std:sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) the whole array and pick the median.

Comment: Use [this code](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Cpp/STL-Algorithms-Helper/Computethesamplestandarddeviation.htm) for standard deviation. For median, use `std::nth_element` with the `n` set to the halfway point.

Comment: Almost identical question with several answers and references to further questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616511/calculate-mean-and-standard-deviation-from-a-vector-of-samples-in-c-using-boos