# What is the meaning of bind<void>(ref(acc), _1)?

Tags: c++, boost

I am attempting to interpret one of the answers to the question "calculate mean and standard deviation from a vector of samples in C++ using boost" found at [Calculate mean and standard deviation from a vector of samples in C++ using Boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616511/calculate-mean-and-standard-deviation-from-a-vector-of-samples-in-c-using-boos).

The question is about how to calculate mean and standard deviation for a vector containing samples using boost. The answer given by David Nehme is as follows.

---

Using accumulators is the way to compute means and standard deviations in boost.

```
accumulator_set<double, stats<tag::variance> > acc;
for_each(a_vec.begin(), a_vec.end(), bind<void>(ref(acc), _1));

cout << mean(acc) << endl;
cout << sqrt(variance(acc)) << endl;
```

---

Can someone explain this answer? It looks a bit like a magical incantation to me.

I do not know what "bind(ref(acc), _1)" means. From reading the Boost bind documentation found at [www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/bind/bind.html](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/bind/bind.html), I can assume that bind refers to boost::bind, ref refers to boost::ref, and _1 refers to the _1 placeholder object defined in boost\bind\placeholders.hpp.

However, I do not know how all that fits together. The documentation on boost::bind is a little vague. It talks about using boost::bind with functions but acc is a variable.

What exactly does the for_each line do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you understand what an iterator is; `for_each` takes a starting iterator, an ending iterator, and a function on which to call on the objects associated with the iterator. [std::for_each](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/)

1. `bind<void>(ref(acc),_1)` is functor (or function object - think of this like a function with internal state) that takes one double and returns nothing - roughly equivalent to `void function(double)`);
2. ref(acc) allows you to minimize the penalty for copying an object; [ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref)
3. acc in this case is an accumulator has the following function within its definition operator()(double value);
4. `_1` is known as a place holder (a little complex, but see [placeholders](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders)) - roughly speaking placeholder acts a mechanism to pass a double into the functor.

Comment: I see what I was missing. I did not realize the significance of the following operator while I was reading the documentation earlier.

  void operator ()(Args const & args)

This is what makes acc a function object and not a simple set or vector. Now the magical incantation makes sense!

Comment: @BenKey acc is already a function object, designed specifically to be passed to (and returned from)  std::for_each as-is.

Comment: @kingtorus Note that `ref` does more than just optimize: the semantics are difference, since the functor isn't copied even if the bind-expression is

Comment: Just to clarify, he probably is using C++11 [since he is using placeholders (although - boost::functional provides something similar)]  - `for_each` should then use move semantics - but will possibly have to copy the functor during the first call. The semantics of the `for_each` is the same (*important*); on the other hand the internal workings of the functor have been optimized (as pointed out by @sehe).

Comment: The semantics for `ref(F)` vs. `F` are **not** the same /in general/. So the phrase `ref(acc) allows you to minimize the penalty for copying an object` seems a tad misleading to me.

Comment: I guess I wasn't that clear, `bind<void>(...)` is the functor. The advantage of the ref is that the internal state (the accumulator) is no longer copied. The entire point of passing an accumulator by reference is spelled out [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/accumulators/user_s_guide.html) - 'but some accumulators are not cheap to copy.'

I guess I glossed over the difference between value and reference semantics because I feel that it is irrelevant towards answering the question.

Comment: so is there a way to do it without `boost::bind` but using c++11/14 features, such as, lambda, bind, or move semantics?