# Getting the variance of a vector of long doubles

Tags: c++, variance

I'm trying to calculate the variance of a vector of long doubles. I've tried implementing other code I've seen, but it doesn't return the correct value.

```
long double variance = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < (v.size() - 1); x++) {
    variance += (v.at(x) - mean) * (v.at(x) - mean);
}
variance /= v.size();
```

For example, if my vector is {1,2,3,4,5}, the above code gives me 2.25. To my understanding the correct answer is 2.

Any help is appreciated, I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Try not to use explicit for loops, try to use STL algorithm like transform. Exact solution to your problem at https://stackoverflow.com/a/12405793/171755

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x < (v.size() - 1)`? This skips the last element. Use `<=` or omit the `- 1`.

The index of the element is `v.size() - 1`, and since `x` must be less than that, the loop breaks before the last element is processed.

Comment: Oh. That was a dumb mistake.