# Why std::transform doesn't guarantee the order (but for_each guarantee the order)? Doesn't this allow trick implementation for performance?

Tags: c++, stl

I just realize the standard doesn't guarantee the order of applying function callback in `std::transform`. And it doesn't allow the callback function or functor have side effect. But at the same time `std::for_each` actually guarantee the order.

One guess is the transform can using high performance algorithm which doesn't guarantee order, But O(N) is the best algorithm already.

So why the standard doesn't make the `transform` have the behavior as `for_each` from the view of apply callback function order? The user will benefit form this guarantee.

Comment: O(N) doesn't tell you anything about the **actual** performance, i.e. it neglects constant factors.

Comment: the standard does guarantee sequential ordering of operation. see new answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This non-restrictive definition allows for parallel computing. An implementation may choose to apply transform function using several threads. See also related question: [STL algorithms and concurrent programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547531/stl-algorithms-and-concurrent-programming)

Think of it as a semantic difference in algorithms (that is, that represents programmer's intent rather than being just another tool). With `for_each` you state that you need a sequential scan. With `transform` you state that you only need to aply a function to every item in the container, but you don't care how it will be done.

Comment: Thanks, that exactly answer my question

Comment: I'm not sure, if this was different in c++11, but according to the last working draft for c++14, there is no requirement on `op`, that would allow `std::transform` to be executed in parallel.

Comment: this answer is incorrect. The specification of the InputIterator concept implicitly disallows a concurrent implementation.

Answer (score 6):

Quoting directly from the standard (copied at end):

You will see from the template declaration of `std::transform<>` that the input iterator parameters must conform to the concept of an `InputIterator`.

An `InputIterator` is one of the most restrictive iterator concepts in c++. It does not support any kind of random access. It is only able to advance.

Therefore any implementation of std::transform that requires the iterator to do anything other than be dereferenced or advance is ill-formed. Remember that by specifying `InputIterator`, the standard is explicitly allowing the use of a `std::istream_iterator` (for example) and the implementation of `std::transform` is required to respect the restrictions therein. It must be written only in terms of the methods available on the `InputIterator` concept.

Therefore, by implication, the implementation of this function *must* access elements sequentially (and therefore transform values sequentially) since *to not do so would break the contract implicit in the interface*.

Therefore the standard **does** (implicitly and quietly) guarantee that `std::transform` initialise its elements sequentially. It would be impossible to write a well-formed implementation of `std::transform` that did not.

> 25.3.4 Transform [alg.transform]

```
template<class InputIterator, class OutputIterator, class UnaryOperation>
OutputIterator
transform(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, OutputIterator result, UnaryOperation op);

template<class InputIterator1, class InputIterator2, class OutputIterator, class BinaryOperation>
OutputIterator
transform(InputIterator1 first1, InputIterator1 last1, InputIterator2 first2, OutputIterator result, BinaryOperation binary_op);
```

> 1 Effects: Assigns through every iterator `i` in the range `[result,result + (last1 - first1))` a new corresponding value equal to `op(*(first1 + (i - result))` or `binary_op(*(first1 + (i - result)), *(first2 + (i - result)))`.
>
> 2 Requires: op and binary_op shall not invalidate iterators or subranges, or modify elements in the ranges [first1,last1], [first2,first2 + (last1 - first1)], and [result,result + (last1 - first1)].
>
> 3 Returns: result + (last1 - first1).
>
> 4 Complexity: Exactly last1 - first1 applications of op or binary_op.
>
> 5 Remarks: result may be equal to first in case of unary transform, or to first1 or first2 in case of binary transform.

Comment: Maybe I am being naive, but couldn't the implementation iterate through the values, put them in a vector or some other structure that did have random access, and then process them in parallel or reverse or something?

Comment: The implementation is free to detect stronger iterator strengths and apply a different (possibly out-of-order) algorithm.

Comment: As the wording stands, one could argue that such an implementation conforms to the standard. I asked a friend of mine who contributes to the c++ standard. His view was that the ambiguity in the wording is an error, and the intent is that the transform function is applied linearly. Whether that's the view of the entire committee I cannot say.

Comment: @clcto Not possible. Among other things, it incurs lots of copies, and the type need not be copyable, and *there's no reliable way for the implementation to detect whether it is copyable*. (`is_copy_constructible` won't work, because it can't detect errors outside the immediate context.)

Comment: Sounds to me like this question needs to be addressed by the committee. And how to use transform if f depends on interation count. std::for_each works, but requires capture of the OutputIt, which is ugly.

Comment: As far as I can see, gcc does not guarantee `std::transform` to transform in order... `std::execution::seq` does not help either.

Answer (score 3):

Despite some earlier answers, I think it is possible to implement std::transform in a parallel way. For instance like this:

1) Fetch all input sequentially.

2) Iterate over OutputIterator, initialising dummy objects and keep a reference to each output.

3) Distribute the input with the corresponding output iterator to different threads, each doing the transformation independently.

Like this, the iterators are only incremented as allowed.

As pointed out by clcto, another implementation could do step 1) first, then create a vector for all output elements, then compute all of these in parallel using the given function argument and then write them sequentially into the output.